# How to add a background image to a Form on TMS Web Core for Delphi

Tags: css, delphi, lazarus, delphi-11-alexandria, tms-web-core

I'm trying to get this done on TMS Web Core via Delphi code where one can give the form a background image.

This is how it would be done in CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url("material.jpeg");
}
```

I would like this to be done in Delphi.
I want this image to be loaded when the Form is created.

I tried `GetFormImage` but that is to take an IMAGE of what is already on the form.

Answer (score 0):

In the form's `OnShow` event, you can use the following code to change the form's background to an image:

```
procedure TMyForm.WebFormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  ImgURL: String;
  StyleImg: String;
begin
  ImgURL := 'https://shaunroselt.com/assets/img/hero-bg.jpg';

  StyleImg := ';background-image: url('+ImgURL+');';
  StyleImg := document.body.getAttribute('style') + StyleImg;

  document.body.setAttribute('style',StyleImg);
end;
```

The code gets the form (body element) and sets a CSS style `background-image` attribute to it.